# using d3 transition in large rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, d3.js, transition

I'm working on a large rails app and am having problems using d3's transition() function.

I'm able to get the code to work in isolation:
http://jsfiddle.net/cjhin/hb38Lqus/1/

```
# coffeescript
nodes = []
nodes.push { radius: 100, x: 100, y: 100 }

vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 200)

circles = vis.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes, (d) -> d.id)

circles.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("fill", "#d84b2a")
  .attr("cx", (d) -> d.x)
  .attr("cy", (d) -> d.y)

circles.transition().duration(500).attr("r", (d) -> d.radius)
```

but when I put the code (verbatim) into the app, the transition does not occur (the circle stays at a a radius of 10).

My hunch is that it's probably a rails gem/plugin issue, or perhaps a name-spacing issue ... but at this point I'm a bit lost.

My gemfile includes the following javascript gems

```
'd3_rails', '~> 3.4.8'
'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
'angularjs-rails', '~> 1.2.16'
'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Months Later I finally found the issue!

Turns out there was a conflict with date.js and D3.js that breaks [D3 transitions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1302).

The workaround is to upgrade date.js to the [version here](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/trunk/build/date-en-US.js).  For some reason it was never labeled as an official release (nor was the version number bumped), but upgrading fixes the issues.